# bindingContext.ModelName is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, defaultmodelbinder

So I'm trying to apply [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222639/286575), but in my implementation bindingContext.ModelName is equal to "".

Here's my viewmodel:

```
public class UrunViewModel
{
    public Urun Urun { get; set; }
    public Type UrunType { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the part of the view that posts the model types:

```
@model UrunViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tablo Ekle";

    var types = new List<Tuple<string, Type>>();
    types.Add(new Tuple<string, Type>("Tuval Baskı", typeof(TuvalBaski)));
    types.Add(new Tuple<string, Type>("Yağlı Boya", typeof(YagliBoya)));
}

<h2>Tablo Ekle</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("UrunEkle", "Yonetici")) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Tablo</legend>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UrunType, new SelectList(types, "Item2", "Item1" ))
```

And here's my custom model binder:

```
public class UrunBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type type)
    {
        var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Urun");

        var model = Activator.CreateInstance((Type)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(Type)));
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);

        return model;
    } 
}
```

Finally, the line in Global.asax.cs:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(UrunViewModel), new UrunBinder());
```

Here inside the overridden `CreateModel` function, in debugging mode I can see that `bindingContext.ModelName` is equal to "". And also, `typeValue` is null so `CreateInstance` function fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need the `bindingContext.ModelName` property for what you are trying to do.

Going by [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding/7222639#7222639), it looks like you can try the following.  First you need a hidden field on your form for the type:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UrunEkle", "Yonetici")) {
    @Html.Hidden("UrunType", Model.Urun.GetType())
```

Then in your model binding (basically copied from Darin Dimitrov):

```
protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
{
    var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("UrunType");
    var type = Type.GetType(
        (string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
        true
    );
    var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
    return model;
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519264/modelbindingcontext-modelname) for more info on how the `bindingContext.ModelName` is populated.

Comment: bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("UrunType") really works. I couldn't get it to create the instance I want yet, but this is a progress. thanks.

Comment: Ok I managed to create the instance, but its derived properties are all null. Only the base class's properties are set